# How to add key and value to map of list of lists in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a map of lists created, and I'm just trying to add to the map as such:

```
val bandMap: Map<Int,List<List<Int>>> = mutableMapOf()

val rsrpList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val rsrqList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val levelList = mutableListOf<Int>()
rsrpList.add(3)
rsrqList.add(4)
levelList.add(1)
val listOfLists = mutableListOf(rsrpList,rsrqList,levelList)
bandMap[3] = listOfLists
```

But "bandMap[3] = listOfLists" says there is mismatch.

```
No set method providing array access
```

Not sure where this would be? It seems as if it doesn't know I'm trying to map something. I tried the put method, but it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Thanks.

Edit:

Thanks Tenfour04 - you helped a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the outer map to be a read-only Map and the inner lists to be read-only Lists in your variable type here:

```
private val bandMap: MutableMap<Int,List<List<Int>>> = mutableMapOf()
```

Even though you are putting MutableLists into your map, they are up-cast to Lists when you retrieve them because of the property type of `bandMap`.

Specify `MutableList` as the type of the inner Lists if you need to mutate them:

```
private val bandMap: MutableMap<Int, List<MutableList<Int>>> = mutableMapOf()
```

or, if you also need to modify the outer list of the lists:

```
private val bandMap: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<MutableList<Int>>> = mutableMapOf()
```

Side note, this three dimensional collection structure is kind of confusing to work with (error-prone). You might be able to come up with a structure that uses a class to make it easier to reason about and work with. I don't really know what your structure represents, but here's a vague example:

```
class Band {
    val rsrpList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val rsrqList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val levelList = mutableListOf<Int>()
}

val bandMap: MutableMap<Int, Band> = mutableMapOf()
bandMap[3] = Band()
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like that fixed something at least. added the issue in my answer still.

Comment: Oops, you need the map to be a MutableMap, too!

Comment: Ok, like this? private val bandMap: mutableMapOf<Int,List<List<Int>>> = mutableMapOf(). I was thinking "= mutableMapOf()" was making that a mutable map?

Comment: It is making a MutableMap, but then you are casting it to a Map because of your property type. See my edited answer for the correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver to a beginner Kotlin'ner like me!